# Second page does not redirect to the specific link

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, jsp, pagination

My Jquery code consists of the following code

```
$('.readControl').click(function() {
                doSubmitPostActions();
                var path = this.id;
                $(location).attr('href', path);
            });
```

Within my index.jsp this is the file which calls the readControl class

```
    <tr id="${item.employee.id}">
    <td>
 <a class="readControl" id="${item.path}" href="#"> ${item.employee.dateControl} </a>
 </td>
    </tr>
```

My query is that I have 12 elements within this date control section and first 10 tables redirect me to the href tag but after 10 elements it doesnt. Is the issue with the pagination or we need to make changes in the Jquery part? If yes, what are the necessary changes within the code?

Comment: Thinking out loud: could it be that the 'next' page does not involve a page reload? If so, do you bind the click event again? Based on the behaviour you describe, it looks like this piece is missing.

Comment: Can you provide me with a sample code for the same since i'm a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSP code should be as follows

```
 <tr id="${item.employee.id}">
        <td>
     <a class="readControl" id="${item.path}" href="#" onclick="javascript:redirectToReadControl(this.id)"> ${item.employee.dateControl} </a>
     </td>
        </tr>
```

Your Jquery code should be replaced with the following outside the `onload` function

```
 function redirectToReadControl(path){
                doSubmitPostActions();
                $(location).attr('href', path);
            }
```